# Drop down selections based on Previous selection

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a little question. I am running an event and its in few cities, different dates and different times. I'm creating a signup form in jQuery / PHP / HTML .  I wan the options to appear based on the previous selection.

I have 3 cities
**"City1" "City2" "City3"**

And "City1" is on
**"22nd July" & "25th July"**

And on "22nd July" there are 2 sessions
**"2pm" & "5pm"**

How can I get started with a form like this? Please give me an example.

Thanks heaps guys

Answer (score 0):

Not going to do it for you, but I can give you a few hints. First, your select needs an onchange function, and they each need unique ids. e.g.

```
<select onchange='update' id='box1'>
```

Next, your onchange function needs to detect the current element, and update the other boxes. I'd suggest storing the data as a multidimensional array. So the update will be something like this:

```
var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
var b2 = document.getElementById('box2');
while(b2.options.length > 0)b2.remove(0);//remove all options currently present
for(var i in boxoptions[id])b2.options[b2.options.length]=new Option(boxoptions[id]['name'], boxoptions[id]['value']);//add new options
```

And, of course, you'll need the array of data, but you can figure the rest out yourself. That help?

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eJn8g/

```
// data
var data = {
    "New York": ["July 20", "July 21"],
    "Miami": ["July 22", "July 23"],
    "San Francisco": ["July 24", "July 25"],
}

// populate menu1
for (var i in data) {
    $('#menu1').append('<option>' + i + '</option>');
}

// populate menu2 based on menu1's value
$('#menu1').change(function() {
    var key = $(this).val();
    $('#menu2').empty();
    for (var i in data[key]) {
        $('#menu2').append('<option>' + data[key][i] + '</option>');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```